# Vim: How to run `:TOhtml` on all files within current directory via a single command?

Tags: vim

I just found the very useful command `:TOhtml`, now I'm looking forward to a command or plugin  that can automatically run `:TOhtml` in current directory, i.e. to convert all source code under a given path, and preserves the directory structure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Kent, it's good to know the `argdo` function.

But just like Ben suggested, the `TOhtml` will leave a bunch of unsaved windows open.

I eventually found a single-command way:

`for i in *.ext; do vim -c TOhtml -c wqa $i ; done`

will do the job.

Appreciate all your helps! :p

Answer (score 8):

vim has `argdo` to let you execute commands on multiple files. you could try:

```
:args **/*.*
:argdo TOhtml
```

Comment: see also :bufdo if you want to execute the command on all buffers (in case you opened new files after starting vim)

Comment: Note that TOhtml by itself will leave a bunch of unsaved windows open containing the conversions. I'd recommend appending a `| w` or a `| wq` to the end of the argdo command to close the automatically created windows.